# User.IsInRole works locally but not in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-ad-b2c

The following code returns Yes when executed in Visual Studio on a local machine but No once the app is published to azure (the same Azure AD user credentials are used both times).

**Edit 1** (06.11.2022):

The user credentials not stored in a database Table but are set via AppRegistration and AppRole in Azure.

```
string isReportingRole;

if (User.IsInRole("ReportingRole"))
{
    isReportingRole = "Yes";
}
else
{
    isReportingRole = "No";
}
```

Authentication is configured like this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        services.AddRazorPages()
             .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureB2C"));

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;

        });

        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("de-DE");
            options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("de-DE"), new CultureInfo("de-DE") };
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    }



public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
    cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "€";

    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
    cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "€";

    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487458/azure-ad-returning-roles-in-claims-but-user-isinrole-returns-false

Comment: I don't think this applies. I do not use ´UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication´. I also cannot add 'TokenValidationParameters' to 'app.UseAuthentication();'

Comment: Where are the user roles and user role assignments on the Azure AD environment? I assume that on your local machine/environment, you have the identity database containing the Users, Roles and UserRole assignments… but what are you using in the Azure environment to achieve your application’s user authentication and authorization?

Comment: No, there is no database containing user or role credentials. The roles are defined in the App-Registration and the AD users are assigned to these roles. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, **`User.IsInRole`** will check the cookies of HTTP Request. If the request contains the role information, it will give the valid information.

By default, **`User.IsInRole`** is a case sensitive you can use alternative **`UserManager.IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), "admin")`**.  I hope you are given valid role if not consider below things

Instead of this

```cs
string isReportingRole;
if (User.IsInRole("isReportingRole")) /*This is False*/
{
    isReportingRole = "Yes";
}
```

Try using below

```cs
string isReportingRole;
if(UserManager.IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), "isReportingRole")) /*This is True!!*/
{
    isReportingRole = "Yes";
}
```

Try adding the below line of code snippet in your **Startup.cs** so that whenever the application start runs it will add the identity so that we can get the role information.

```cs
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```